Unity// Пргоблема с анимациями
В моей игре есть две кнопки переключения вправо и влево. Чтобы это было красиво я накинул на них анимацию небольшого увеличения при наводе на кнопку курсором. Анимация работает,когда навожу курсором на первую или вторую кнопку они увеличиваются. Но дело в том, что когда нажимаешь на одну из двух кнопок анимация пропадает,** у той, на которую нажимал**, но у второй кнопки, на которую не было нажатия, анимация работает. Потом я нажимаю на вторую кнопку, у нее появляется анимация, но при последующих нажатиях она пропадает, НО появляется у первой кнопки. Приложу видео
https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20241121yONuNvXn

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
